# Laravel installer - Php version problam for laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a new project with latest version 5.6  of Laravel which required PHP 7.1.3 via Laravel installer.

```
Laravel new project
```

I have also update the php version to "PHP-7.2.2" but still getting the following error.

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

[image]

With composer it is working perfectly.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project
```

Comment: when you type `php -v` on your command line does it actually say PHP 7.2.2? The errors seem to indicate you're using 7.1.1

Comment: It says 7.1.1. So It mean's i have to update the entertainment viable?

Comment: If you've ran `php -v` on your command line, and it says you're using 7.1.1, then you have PHP 7.1.1 installed on your system. You don't have 7.2.2. You will need to upgrade your PHP installation.

Comment: update php7.1-cli

Comment: check whether you change your default php version to new one. If you are using wamp you can do this in your system tray.

Comment: I have changed the entertainment viable `php -v` but it is still showing  7.1.1

Comment: @shah You haven't installed 7.2.2, regardless of environment variables. You **need** to install 7.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system.

If you are using Linux based and apache i.e LAMP Stack then you need to run

to disable php7.1 `sudo a2dismod php7.1` and enable php7.2`sudo a2enmod php7.2`